# Wagtail Custom Document Model

Tags: wagtail

I understand from this thread https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/2001

that you can customise the Wagtail Document Model, as you can the Image Model, to add extra fields to it. What I can't find is any documentation on how to do this. If anyone has any suggestions on where to start that would be great. I'm new to wagtail so any help much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Custom document model can be implemented in a similar way as a [custom image model](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/advanced_topics/images/custom_image_model.html). To add your own document model (let's call it `CustomDocument`) you should do the following:

1. Create a model that inherit from `wagtail.wagtaildocs.models.AbstractDocument`. Should be something like:

   ```
   class CustomDocument(AbstractDocument):
       # Add your custom model fields here

       admin_form_fields = (
           'title',
           'file',
           'collection',
           'tags'
           # Add your custom model fields into this list,
           # if you want to display them in the Wagtail admin UI.
       )
   ```
2. Register a `post_delete` signal handler to remove a file from your disk once document record deleted in the database. It should be something like this:

   ```
   # Receive the post_delete signal and delete the file associated with the model instance.
   @receiver(post_delete, sender=CustomDocument)
   def document_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
       # Pass false so FileField doesn't save the model.
       instance.file.delete(False)
   ```
3. Set the `WAGTAILDOCS_DOCUMENT_MODEL` setting to point to your model. Example:

   ```
   `WAGTAILDOCS_DOCUMENT_MODEL = 'your_app_label.CustomDocument'`
   ```

Comment: That's great, thank you - and thanks for the swift response :-)

Comment: You should select m1kola's answer to your question @gbmillard if this solved your problem. That way they will be rewarded and it will be easier for others skimming this page.

Answer (score 0):

Just small correction to @m1kola's answer: you don't need to register post_delete signal. Wagtail already does it:

```
def post_delete_file_cleanup(instance, **kwargs):
    # Pass false so FileField doesn't save the model.
    transaction.on_commit(lambda: instance.file.delete(False))


def register_signal_handlers():
    # in example above it returns CustomDocument model and register signal 
    Document = get_document_model() 
    post_delete.connect(post_delete_file_cleanup, sender=Document)
```

See their [github](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/documents/signal_handlers.py#L12)