# Generating WagtailCMS Document Previews

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

Is there a way to extend Wagtail's documents to show file previews?  There's a [service](http://filepreviews.io/blog/2017/04/20/adding-document-previews-to-wagtail/) ( I have not tested ), which looks cool, but the free plan to Pro plan is a huge leap in cost. I am hoping someone has figured this out already and can point me to the solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FilePreviews.io's 100 documents a month on the free plan seems pretty generous to me. You could try to build something similar, e.g. using ImageMagick to create PDF thumbnails:

http://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/11/18/how-to-create-thumbnails-for-pdfs-with-imagemagick-on-linux/

and use a service like Aspose to convert common file formats to PDFs:

https://www.aspose.com

Or you could do it manually, by adding a thumbnail field to your document model, and telling users to provide their own thumbnails.

But if you or your client are uploading more than 100 documents a month, and you want reliable thumbnail generation for multiple document types, $49 a month may be better value than working it all out yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I will look at documentation again.  They won't be adding more than a 100 per month but already have over 400 in the system that would need thumbs. If I don't go that way, would you be able to share how to add a thumb field to the document model?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43389396/201316 for custom document models